# Ajax sets global vars, but outside the value disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The settings on the object window, only get "fixed" if I call the function[ctrUpadateCount]  under an alert, if I do a direct call it wont work.
Any idea why? I had the same issue on another project. And had to apply a solution which cannot be applied here.
I've tried to explain the code bellow...
p.s.: sorry for bad English.

```
function ctrUpdateCount(idCtrForm)
{     
   $.ajaxSetup({ assync: false});
   tableName= 'clients';
   p_comando="select count(*) total from "+tableName;
   $.post("execute.php", {comando : p_comando}, function(json){           
    v_total=json[1].total ; // <= this retuns 3
    window['ctrBuffer_'+idCtrForm].count=v_total;
    alert("count inside = "+ window['ctrBuffer_'+idCtrForm].count );//this alerts 3
   },'json'); 
}

jQuery.fn.extend( { ctrLoad: function()
   { 
    if( $(this).get(0).tagName =='FORM'){       
     idCtrForm=$(this).attr('id');
     alert("direct count ="+ctrUpdateCount(idCtrForm) ); // this will alert 3
                                                         // and so  the next alert
     //teste=ctrUpdateCount(idCtrForm); // but if I use this, 
                                        //the next alert will show  "undefined"
     alert("count after = "+ window['ctrBuffer_'+idCtrForm].count );
    }
  } 
})
```

Comment: Oh, are you sending raw SQL over Ajax? Little Bobby Tables will be excited.

Comment: Good grief this just gets asked over and over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "ctrUpdateCount" function is using `$.post()`, which is **asynchronous**. It's impossible to have the function return a value determined by the result of that asynchronous operation; it's inherently nonsensical.

I really can't tell what you're trying to do, but basically you have to do what you need to do with the results of the "POST" operation **inside** the callback function to `$.post()`.

Comment: ok, this code is nothing like safe, but my main doubt is why this window['anything'].count , returns a value inside the function and not outside ?

Comment: The `$.post()` call returns immediately, but it takes time for the browser to complete the HTTP request.  The function you pass in to `$.post()` will **not** run immediately - it runs when the HTTP request is complete.